# Need explanation for simple differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I can't figure out this really simple linear equation:

$$x'=x$$

I know that the result should be an exponential function with $t$ in the exponent, but I can't really say why. I tried integrating both sides but it doesn't seem to work. I know this is shameful noob question, but I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: $x'=x$, $dx/dt=x$, $dx=x\,dt$, $(1/x)\,dx=dt$, now integrate.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed.

Comment: Just think about which function has a derivative equal to itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x \Leftrightarrow  dt=\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Comment: We could also write this solution without using infinitesimals: $\frac{dx}{dt} = x \implies \frac{1}{x} \frac{dx}{dt} = 1 \implies \log | x | = t + c$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}=x(t)$, so: $\dfrac{dx(t)}{x(t)}=dt$, integrating the two sides you get:$\ln(x(t))-\ln(x(0))=t$ and finally:
$$x(t)=x(0)\exp(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x'=x \Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} dx = 1 \ dt \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{x} dx = \int 1 \ dt \Rightarrow \ln(x)= t + C \Rightarrow x(t)=e^te^c.$$

$\cdot \ \text{Let A}=e^c \ \text{then} \ x(t) = Ae^t$

Comment: In your argument you make implicitly the assumption that $x$ is not equal to zero. Though, $x(t)=0$ is also a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's unnecessary to treat $dx$ and $dt$ as independent entities ("infinitesimals") when solving a differential equation like this.

One way to solve it (other than just guessing the solution) is this:
\begin{align}
& x'(t) = x(t) \\
\implies & x'(t) - x(t) = 0 \\
\implies & x'(t) e^{-t} - x(t) e^{-t} = 0 \qquad (\heartsuit)\\
\implies & x(t) e^{-t} = C \quad \text{for some } C \in \mathbb R \quad (\spadesuit)\\
\implies & x(t) = Ce^t.
\end{align}
To go from ($\heartsuit$) to ($\spadesuit$), we took antiderivatives of both sides, using the product rule in reverse.

This is a standard trick which can be used to solve any first order linear ODE.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof using only differentiation:** Try the family of functions

$$
x(t) = x(0) e^t
$$

as solution (just differentiate)

$$
x'(t) = x(0) \frac{d}{dt} e^t = x(0) e^t = x(t)
$$

and proof the uniqueness. 
This is usually done by assuming a second solution $y(t)$ with

$$
y'(t) = y(t)
$$

then

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \frac{y(t)}{x(t)} = 
\frac{y'(t) x(t) - y(t) x'(t)}{x^2(t)} =
\frac{y(t) x(t) - y(t) x(t)}{x^2(t)} =
0
$$

for $x(t) \ne 0$, which implies

$$
y(t) = C \, x(t) \\
y(0) = C \, x(0)
$$

for some constant $C$, thus if a second solution exists, it is unique
if it has the same initial condition 
otherwise it is of the same form as the first one, 
only differing by the multiplicative constant.

This proof is derived from Grönwald's lemma.

**Proof using Integration:**

$$
x'(t) = x(t) \iff \\
0 = 
x'(t) - x(t) = 
\left( x'(t) - x(t) \right) \, e^{-t} =
\frac{d}{dt} \left( x(t) \, e^{-t} \right) \iff \\
x(t) \, e^{-t} = C \iff \\
x(t) = C \, e^t
$$

This one used the integrating factor $e^{-t}$.

Comment: The solution is **not** unique. There is a family of solutions given by $f_c(t) = c e^t$ with c a non-zero constant and the trivial solution $f_0(t) = 0$.

Comment: I coorected the constant myself. However that set which only differs by the constant is unique.

Answer (score 0):

I like to remember that $\frac{d}{dt}ln x=\frac{x'}{x}$.  Thus, very quickly we have $$\frac{d}{dt}lnx=1 \rightarrow ln x=t+C \rightarrow x=Ce^t$$